# Which iPhone does an iPad running an iPhone only app correspond to?

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, ipad

Every once in a while, my iPhone only app seems to crash for users running it on iPad.

Recently I found a crash report at globalinit pointing to the initialisation of this enum type which is used heavily for design and sizes.

```
static var iPhone = IPhone(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)!
```

It seems the iPad device will not match any of these heights so that nil crashes the app (This being an iPad Air with iOS 11).
On the simulator, all iPad devices seem to correspond to an existing iPhone size when running an iPhone only app.

```
enum IPhone: String {
  case SE, normal, plus, X, XSMax

  init?(height: CGFloat) {
    switch height {
    case 568: self = .SE
    case 667: self = .normal
    case 736: self = .plus
    case 812: self = .X
    case 896: self = .XSMax
    default:
       return nil
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, I'd never want to return nil and instead incorporate possible iPad screen sizes which begs the question: Which iPhone does an iPad "simulate" when running my app?
I've recently read that from iOS 12 on, iPads will display iPhone apps no longer in 3/4 format but in 16/9.
Which is the best way to handle this so that any iPad running this app will correspond to one of my existing designs?

Comment: Relying on fixed values is going to fail for the next generation(s) of iPhones anyway, so if possible make use of size classes and the screen bounds (which you already query with `UIScreen.main.bounds`).

Comment: You should never be checking for specific devices. Use auto layout and constraints. Make decisions based on view sizes, not devices.

Answer (score 0):

Below reference tells that after iOS 12 all the iPhone only applications will run on iPad with iPhone 6's resolution. Change your default to `self = .normal` and I think you will be good to go.

https://ioshacker.com/ipad/ios-12-improves-experience-of-using-iphone-apps-on-ipad